# Showing less then 1% on the BootStrap progress bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am using the bootstrap progress bar to show the percentage of miles covered by someone from a total of 23,872 miles.

For example if user A covered only 5 miles which means:

5/23872 = 0.00020945 * 100 = **0.02094504** miles.

Currently anything below 1% does not show up on the progress bar.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to be able to show the percentage of miles below 1 the bar so it lights up green just the 28% in the image above.

**Code for Conversion:**

```
// Calculating Percentages for each region
var ukPercent = $scope.ukTotal / 23872;
var apacPercent = $scope.apacTotal / 23872;
var naPercent = $scope.naTotal / 23872;

$scope.ukPercentage = ukPercent * 100;
$scope.naPercentage = naPercent * 100;
$scope.apacPercentage = apacPercent * 100;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "below 0%"? Do you mean a negative number?

Comment: @NewDev Sorry thats my fault. I mean values less then 1. For example: 0.02, 0.5, 0.000222 etc Apologies I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: You can if you round it to one decimal.

Comment: @user2190986, it does show under 1%. But if the progress bar's total actual width is small, then for some low % (could be even above 1%) which would be sub-pixel width, the browser won't render it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care if how much less than 1% it is, how about using [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to just start at one percent and then start making meaningful progress after that.

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
var $traveled = $("#traveledMiles"),
    $total = $("#totalMiles"),
    $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');

$($traveled).add($total).keyup(function(){

  var percent = $traveled.val() / $total.val() * 100;

  // at least 1%
  percent = Math.max(percent,1);

  $progressBar
    .css('width', percent+'%')
    .attr('aria-valuenow', percent)
    .children(".sr-only").html(percent+'%'); 

}).keyup();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="traveledMiles">Traveled Miles</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="traveledMiles"
         placeholder="Enter Traveled Miles" value="5">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="totalMiles">Total Miles</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalMiles" 
         placeholder="Enter Total Miles" value="23872">
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  style="width: 60%;"
       aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <span class="sr-only">60%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you have a label, you could even follow [Bootstrap's suggestion](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-label):

> To ensure that the label text remains legible even for low percentages, consider adding a min-width to the progress bar.

Like this:

```html
<div class="progress-bar" style="min-width: 2em;">
```

```js
var $traveled = $("#traveledMiles"),
    $total = $("#totalMiles"),
    $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');

$($traveled).add($total).keyup(function(){

  var percent = $traveled.val() / $total.val() * 100;

  // at least 1%
  percent = Math.max(percent,1);
  
  // round off decimals
  percent = Math.round(percent);
  
  // max of 100%
  percent = Math.min(percent,100);

  $progressBar
    .css('width', percent+'%')
    .attr('aria-valuenow', percent)
    .html(percent+'%'); 

}).keyup();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="traveledMiles">Traveled Miles</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="traveledMiles"
         placeholder="Enter Traveled Miles" value="5">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="totalMiles">Total Miles</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalMiles" 
         placeholder="Enter Total Miles" value="23872">
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  style="min-width: 2em;width: 60%;"
       aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    60%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to use a variable called something like "realProgress" to keep track of the decimal value of your progress bar. Since a bootstrap progress bar only works with integers you can update it's value like so (in Javascript):

realProgress = 0.0;
realProgress += some percentage of progress made;

$("#my-progress-bar").css("width", math.Floor(realProgress) + "%");

This way, the progress bar's value still get updated in a way that is meaningful to the user.