# how to overlay multiple children divs in parent div?

Tags: html

I almost burn out cause of this problem.

I want show progress bar like below image

[progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVF69.png)

I mark up as below but fail...

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="position:absolute; width:75%; background:green;"></div>
    <div class="value" style="position:absolut; left:0; margin:0 auto; color:yellow;">75%</div> => center of parent div
</div>
```

how I get pretty progress bar??

please donate your knowledge.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code contains a typo. Check the style for the class `value`. Maybe this code can give you some ideas:

```html
<div class="container" style="position:relative; width:100px; background:#fff; height:20px; border: solid 1px #000">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="position:absolute; width:75%; height:20px; background:green;"></div>
    <div class="value" style="position:absolute; left:0; margin:0 auto; color:yellow; text-align:center; width:100%;">75%</div>
</div>
```

If you want the container to be a rounded rectangle, use `border-radius`.

Also, it's probably a good idea to put all the css into an external file or within a `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp)
for bootstrap progress bars they match what you're after.

You need bootstrap in your project, There are two ways to get Bootstrap. You can download Bootstrap from this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/) or include Bootstrap from a CDN using this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Using the latest version of Bootstrap (v3) you can include the following code taken from [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-label) which gives you a progress bar with a label.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        60%
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i used it. but in my case, some of values are lower than 1%.
i can't see the value clearly

Comment: you could add decimal values using jquery or javascript

Comment: check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210218/showing-less-then-1-on-the-bootstrap-progress-bar) of stackoverflow it may help